# SQL Access Sentence

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I been trying to use this sentences that i made in SQL Server Management Studio, on access with no luck, after hours googling, i think they use different languages, can someone help me turn these in Access language?

```
select c.id_client 'Client ID',
c.client_name 'First Name'
c.client_lname 'Last Name'
from client c join bills b
on c.id_client = b.id_client join bill_detail d
on d.bill_num=b.bill_num
where month (b.date)=3
and year(b.date)= year(getdate())
group by c.id_client, c.client_name,c.client_lname
having d.price > (select avg(prirce) from bill_detail)


select s.id_seller 'Seller ID',
s.seller_name 'First Name',
s.seller_lname 'Last Name',
avg(quantity*d.price),
from sellers s join bills b
on v.id_seller=b.id_seller join bill_detail d
on b.bill_num = d.bill_num
group by s.id_seller, s.seller_name, s.seller_lname
having avg (quantity*d.price) < (select avg(quantity*d.price) from             
bill_detail)

select date 'Date',
sum(quantity) 'Tickets Sold',
sum(quantity*d.price) 'Total Amount Sold',
avg(quantity*d.price) 'Average Amount Sold',
from bills b join bill_detail d
on b.bill_num = d.bill_num
group by date
```

Sry, they were in spanish, hence the awfull english. And thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Useful references:

[Converting Access Queries to SQL Server](https://www.databasejournal.com/features/msaccess/article.php/3705151/Converting-Access-Queries-to-SQL-Server.htm)

[T-SQL Equivalents for Microsoft Access VBA Functions](https://www.databasejournal.com/features/msaccess/article.php/3865076/T-SQL-Equivalents-for-Microsoft-Access-VBA-Functions.htm)

I think these will work.. (it's been a while)

```
SELECT
      client.id_client    [client id]
    , client.client_name  [first name]
    , client.client_lname [last name]
FROM (client
JOIN bills ON client.id_client = bills.id_client)
JOIN bill_detail ON bill_detail.bill_num = bills.bill_num
WHERE MONTH(bills.date) = 3
AND YEAR(bills.date) = YEAR(DATE())
GROUP BY
      client.id_client
    , client.client_name
    , client.client_lname
HAVING d.price > (
      SELECT
            AVG(prirce)
      FROM bill_detail
)
;
```

For some reason Access likes parentheses in the from clause. No idea why. There should be MONTH() & YEAR() . Don't recall if Access like table aliases, so I removed them and don't use single quotes for column labels (don't do this is SQL Server either).

```
SELECT
      sellers.id_seller    [seller id]
    , sellers.seller_name  [first name]
    , sellers.seller_lname [last name]
    , AVG(quantity * bill_detail.price)
FROM (sellers
JOIN bills ON v.id_seller = bills.id_seller)
JOIN bill_detail ON bills.bill_num = bill_detail.bill_num
GROUP BY
      sellers.id_seller
    , sellers.seller_name
    , sellers.seller_lname
HAVING AVG(quantity * bill_detail.price) < (
      SELECT
            AVG(quantity * bill_detail.price)
      FROM bill_detail
)
;
```

Aside from table & column aliases changes these 2 should be ok.

```
SELECT
      datex                   [date]
    , SUM(quantity)           [tickets sold]
    , SUM(quantity * bill_detail.price) [total amount sold]
    , AVG(quantity * bill_detail.price) [average amount sold]
FROM (bills 
JOIN bill_detail ON bills.bill_num = bill_detail.bill_num)
GROUP BY
      datex
;
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what i was looking for. Thank you very much mate

Answer (score 0):

```
having d.price > (select avg(prirce) from bill_detail)
```

I think you should change it to `avg(price)` instead of `avg(prirce)`. 
(Must be spelling mistake only)

Comment: That is just when i typed it here, the original one (they're in spanish) is correctly spelled. Thanks tho.